# Change Message Preview text in iMessages

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, imessage-extension

I'm developing a iMessages Extension app using Swift3 in Xcode. Everything is working good. I am curious if I can change the preview message to my app name in the messages display. I have attached the screenshot to explain it more.

[image: Screenshot showing problem area]